# Why is the following function not in scope when defined in a where clause?

Tags: haskell

```
import               Data.Char (chr, ord)

num2Str :: Int -> String
num2Str n | n < 26 = [num2Chr n]
num2Str n          = num2Chr n : num2Str (n - 26)
  where {
    num2Chr :: Int -> Char;
    num2Chr n = chr(97 + n `mod` 26)
  }
```

This results in the error

```
    * Variable not in scope: num2Chr :: Int -> Char
    * Perhaps you meant `num2Str' (line 132)
    |
132 | num2Str n | n < 26 = [num2Chr n]
    |                       ^^^^^^^
```

I tried a few alternatives to the layout but none seemed to work.

**Minor update**

The code had some logic errors in it unrelated to the question; here is a corrected version:

```
import               Data.Char (chr, ord)
num2LcStr :: Int -> String
num2LcStr n | n < 26    = [num2Chr n] 
            | otherwise = 'z' : num2LcStr (n - 26)
  where
    num2Chr nn = chr(97 + nn `mod` 26)
```

Comment: side note: you should also think of how to handle the case of negative integer input

Comment: I have a feeling it will be throwing my first Haskell error/exception, or whatever the equivalent is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `num2Char` function is not in scope for the first definition `num2Str n | n < 26` because the `where` clause is only "scoped" to the second definition `num2Str n`. The easiest way to circumvent your issue is to modify the function as follows by just separating the functions:

```
import Data.Char (chr, ord)

num2Str :: Int -> String
num2Str n | n < 26 = [(num2Chr n)]
num2Str n          = num2Chr n : num2Str (n - 26)

num2Chr :: Int -> Char
num2Chr n = chr(97 + n `mod` 26)
```

However, in the interest of style it is probably best to fully utilize guards:

```
num2Str :: Int -> String
num2Str n | n < 26    = [(num2Chr n)]
          | otherwise = num2Chr n : num2Str (n - 26)
  where
    num2Chr :: Int -> Char
    num2Chr n = chr(97 + n `mod` 26)
```

I would recommend the above style(s) for completeness, conciseness, and correctness.

Side note on syntax: do not use brackets around the where clause and no need for the semicolon.

If you really want to keep the code similar and to illustrate what I mean about `where` clauses:

```
num2Str :: Int -> String
num2Str n | n < 26 = [(num2Chr n)]
  where 
    num2Chr n = chr(97 + n `mod` 26)
num2Str n          = num2Chr n : num2Str (n - 26)
  where 
    num2Chr n = chr(97 + n `mod` 26)
```

This is valid, but the style is poor. Each `where` is scoped to the function above it. For more information and reference: http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where

Comment: Great, the first option was what I went with to get by, and the second option was apparently what I had forgotten and was looking for.